# Using the WebSharper compiler to write Node.js applications

Tags: javascript, node.js, f#, websharper

I was wondering if it is possible to use the WebSharper compiler to write Node.js applications in F#. Are there any resources available that could show me how to do this? Are there any good reasons not to try to do this?

Comment: I have one good reason not to do it - I don't know F#!!

Comment: Completely cool idea! If you have a few spare hours, I suggest just trying - it should be possible. You might have to bind the core libraries of Node.js (and some other libraries you might need) - there are online resources. Please do blog about your success, and difficulties!

Comment: Personally I think its important to just use different languages for different jobs.

Comment: https://github.com/martydill/node.fs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*[I would post this as a comment, but it got a bit too long...]*

Here is another good reason not to do it - F# *agents* and *asynchronous workflows* provide a concurrent programming model that is in many aspects much better than what Node.js provides. For example:

- it gives you both concurrency and also true parallelism so you can write code that does not block the system when it needs to do some work using the CPU
- asynchronous workflows provide easy way to handle exceptions and handle resources
  (you can use `try .. with` in asynchronous (or event-based) code)
- the agent-based programming model gives you a great way to store state

If you can use F# to write your server-side application, then you can as well us the powerful abstractions it providers. See [Server-Side Functional Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273081.aspx) for a brief introduction. I also did a talk [F# on the server-side](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/scala/talk-by-tomas-more-info-coming-soon) which has been recorded and discusses the same topic.

This is not necessarily a reason why *not to try this*. Trying this might be fun and if you like F# language, but want to use in Node.js environment, then it would be very useful to have this.